# Spring - execute query before application shutdown (tests)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, shutdown-hook, application-shutdown

I'm running SpringBoot 2.1 with Sprind Data JPA/Hibernate as persistence layer. I run into problem to succesfully run query, *in my tests*, before application shutdown.

Details:

During application context startup I'm executing a query via JPA (let's say this query translates to following SQL `"insert into mytable('mycolumn') values ('abc')`).

Now I need to execute another query before application is shutdown. For given example this would be `"update mytable set mycolumn = 'xyz' where mycolumn = 'abc'`

I managed to execute the query by using @PreDestroy on my configuration class

```
@Configuration
MyConfig {

   @Autowired
   private MyTransactionalService myService;

   @PreDestroy
   public void doQuery() {
      mySerivce.runMyQuery(); 

  }
}
```

`mySerivce.runMyQuery()` delagates to `myRepository` (which is Spring Data JPA Repository) to call update query:

```
MyRepository extends JpaRepository(String, Something) {

   @Modifying
   @Query("UPDATE myEntity e SET e.myColumn = 'xyz' WHERE e.myColumn = 'abc")' 
   void runMyQuery();
}
```

The method annotated with `@PreDestroy` executes but when the query is executed by H2 (inmemory db running inside my spring tests) it throws exception saying that table does not exist.

The thing is that table surely existed before as I'm able to execute INSERT on that table during application startup (see beginning of the post).

My guess would be that the shudtown process is in progress, so the in-memory database was cleared out... thus there is no table.

Is there anyway to ensure query is executed while connection to database is still healthy and removal of tables did not happen yet (upon application context shutdown) ?

Comment: why do you need to update a table right before database destruction?

Comment: In tests this is destructed. In live system database will be persistent. I really need that for real database (SQL server)...  but I would like to be able to test this behavior with in-mem db in tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to overcome this by using `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE";` init parameter

```
String url = "jdbc:h2:~/test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE";
```

In this case H2 does not kill the database and keeps it available during the shutdown process.

Answer (score 2):

`@Predestroy` works as expected, just put `@PreDestroy` annotation on some method in you Application class. I created an example here. To test quickly i used sql files to initialize my database as it is described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html), by you can also use a service for it. When i shutdown the application the database is updated as wanted. Please try :

Dependencies in : pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.zpavel</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>1.4.199</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Model :

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Foo {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String bar;
}
```

Repository :

```
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {
}
```

src/main/resources/schema.sql :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;

CREATE TABLE foo (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
  bar VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
);
```

src/main/resources/data.sql :

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('baz');
```

src/main/resources/application.properties :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {  
    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepository;

    // keep main method here

    @PreDestroy
    private void shutdown() {
        fooRepository.deleteAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the code snippet with " just put `@PreDestroy` annotation on some method in you Application class". You pasted a lot of code but not the one which answers the question. Thanks.

Comment: Right. Forgotten it. I wiil complete my answer.

Comment: Did it work for you ?(I put the code of Application class)

Comment: Your example does not use imem database but MariaDb. With persistent database there is no problem. Another thing is that in my case injecting FooService in Application class is not possible due to how module dependencies are organized (i.e Application does not see FooRepository)